# xml and condition by dateTime

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml

XML

```
<CalendarFairs> 
    <CalendarFair>
        <DateStart>2011-04-05T00:00:00</DateStart>
       <DateEnd>2011-04-09T00:00:00</DateEnd>
        <Title>aaaa</Title>   
       <IdExecutive>1</IdExecutive>
   </CalendarFair>
  <CalendarFair>
      <DateStart>2011-04-16T00:00:00</DateStart>
      <DateEnd>2011-04-19T00:00:00</DateEnd>
      <Title>bbb</Title>
      <IdExecutive>2</IdExecutive>
  </CalendarFair>
<CalendarFairs>
```

Code

```
  var elements = from element in doc.Descendants("CalendarFair")
                           where DateTime.Parse (element.Elements ("DateStart").ToString())==DateTime.Now 
                           select new
                           {
                               dateStart = element.Element("DateStart").Value,
                               dateEnd=element.Element("DateEnd").Value,
                               title=element.Element("Title").Value,
                               idExcutive = element.Element("IdExecutive").Value ,
                           };

foreach (var item in elements)//send this error

            {}
System.FormatException: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is a 
unknown word starting at index 0.
```

why error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change it as follows:

```
var elements = from element in doc.Descendants("CalendarFair")
               let start = element.Element("DateStart").Value
               where DateTime.Parse (start)==DateTime.Now.Date
               select new
               {
                   dateStart = start,
                   dateEnd=element.Element("DateEnd").Value,
                   title=element.Element("Title").Value,
                   idExcutive = element.Element("IdExecutive").Value ,
               };
```

**EDIT:** based on the XML you have posted the query above works pretty well. Try to test it with this input:

```
<CalendarFairs> 
    <CalendarFair>
        <DateStart>2011-04-05T00:00:00</DateStart>
       <DateEnd>2011-04-09T00:00:00</DateEnd>
        <Title>aaaa</Title>   
       <IdExecutive>1</IdExecutive>
   </CalendarFair>
  <CalendarFair>
      <DateStart>2011-03-20T00:00:00</DateStart>
      <DateEnd>2011-04-19T00:00:00</DateEnd>
      <Title>bbb</Title>
      <IdExecutive>2</IdExecutive>
  </CalendarFair>
</CalendarFairs>
```

*Note that I have inserted today's start date*. Actually I think the result was empty just because there weren't entries with actual date.

Comment: Does this throw an exception? If yes try to check if `DateStart` element exists inside `CalendarFair`. Otherwise the comparison to `DateTime.Now.Date`, as I've just edited in my answer.

Comment: DateStart exist; dateTime.now.Date does not work,too. where DateTime.Parse (start)==DateTime.Now.Date;  start does not property value

Comment: I am sorry but I can't understand what you are saying. Anyway it seems strange that, also in this way, your program does not work. Could you please insert in your original post the XML you are working with?

Comment: I think the problem is that `start`is a string, so the line should read: `where DateTime.Parse (start)==DateTime.Now.Date`

Comment: Are you working with ASP.NET? What's the date in your server?

Comment: Please check `DateTime.Now` value.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like one or more of your input `<DateStart>` strings is not in a valid `DateTime` format.

Can you post some sample input XML?

It may be that you need to provide the date format using ParseExact - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx